# How to load a flash game from a website in an application?

Tags: actionscript, load

How can I load a flash (ActionScript ?) game from a website through an application? I'm tired of playing in my browser and I want to make a tool which has bigger dimensions, the game screen will be centered but there will be all kinds of handy stuff all around the centered screen, to make things easier. How would I do that? I've heard things like using iframe but I have really no clue where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SwfLoader class , keep in mind that some games may have code that checks if they run in a browser and that are on the correct site so not all games will work with that.
To use swfloader you need to find the url of the sef of the game.
You could also use the HTML component (or the HTMLLoader) to load the website ,then you could write some javascript code and make it run to remove some clutter from the webpage, I am not sure if you could do a zoom.

All the above would work in an Adobe AIR application, research the class I mentioned and experiment.

If you just want the game and not add any other extras you can grab the swf and run it directly,you need to download from Adobe the standalone player (not plugin)